# calling variables from inner php function to use in outer function

Tags: php, nested-function

currently I have the following code

inside my 'function.php' is

```
function calcTime($database_name,$currentTime){

    global $startTime;
    global $endTime;

    ...calcutions

    return $startTime;
    return $endTime;
}//end calcTime()
```

inside my main 'index.php' I have

```
include('/function.php');

$databaseName = foo;

$currentTime = 12.30;

function begin($database_name,$currentTime){

    ...some calculations

    calcTime($database_name,$currentTime); //calling the function from other file

echo $startTime;

echo $endTime;

}// end begin()
```

The problem I am having is that the variables that are declared inside the inner function do not pass through to the outer function. I have declared the variables globals and returned them. Not sure whats going on.

something interesting though, if I echo calcTime($database_name,$currentTime); the $startTime is returned but not $endTime.

Please help. I have functions that are used throughout other functions that I would like to use in this fashion. Thank you!!

Comment: I am not an expert in PHP `global` but at least I know that you do not have to return what’s global, or do not have to set global, what you return. I **think** (that’s where I am uncertain) that `global` is used when you have a variable that already exists in the outer code **before** you use it inside a function. But in your code $startTime is not used **before** the function call. Just use `list($startTime, $endTime) = calcTime($database_name,$currentTime);` and remove the two `global` commands. And of course change the two `return` to `return array($startTime, $endTime);`

Comment: You can only ever return once from a function. You may however return an array of values or an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `global` keyword in PHP is used to access global variables which were declared outside of the function. It's syntactic sugar for writing `$var =& $GLOBALS['var']`.

There are at least two options how you could return your two variables from your function: call-by-ref or returning an array:

```
function calcTime($database_name,$currentTime){
    return array('start' => $startTime, 'end' =>  $endTime);
}

$times = calcTime(…, …);
echo $times['start'], ' and ', $times['end'];
// or:
list($start, $end) = calcTime(…, …);
echo $start, ' and ', $end;
```

Or, passing the arguments as references:

```
function calcTime($database_name,$currentTime, &$startTime, &$endTime){
    $startTime = …;
    $endTime = …;
}

$startTime = 0;
$endTime = 0;
calcTime(…, …, $startTime, $endTime);
echo $startTime, ' and ', $endTime;
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply put: the calling scope isn't `global` scope either... So for it to work, the variables would *have* to be declared `global` there as well. Do note that (over)use of globals is considered bad practice, and a hell to debug for you fellow coders (or even you after some time has passed). Favor parameters & returns.

** remember every function is isolated on php, when you set a global or variable on one function that will be visible only on function scope

Of course, you can return only **one** value, but that might as well be a more complex one, like:

```
return array('startTime' => $startTime,'endTime' => $endTime);
```

Answer (score 2):

The first issue is that `global` in PHP is a bit counter-intuitive. I know it confused me. It doesn't make a variable inside the function accessible outside; rather, it allows you to use variables in the function which were declared outside, eg:

```
$foo = 'hello';
function bar() {
    global $foo;
    echo $foo;
}
```

What you want to do is return both the variables. However, you can only `return` once. As soon as PHP reaches a `return` statement, it ends the function, so the second one never runs.

What I'd advise doing is returning an array containing both values, eg:

```
return array('startTime' => $startTime, 'endTime' => $endTime);
```

Then, you can use `extract` to make them variables again:

```
extract( calcTime() );
echo $startTime;
echo $endTime;
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining the issue with globals. I had no idea. Whats the difference between declaring a global inside the function or passing the variable through the function? for instance, in your example above, why not just function bar($foo) ? Would that be the same or is there a benefit to doing it that way?

Comment: Fewer globals is better. If you can pass a variable as parameter, do it.